# Running a local copy of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, database-backups

Our company has a SQL Server 2008 R2 database on one of our servers. We would like to be able to make a copy of this database and open it off of a local machine; however, the size is greater than 10GB so the Express version won't do it. Is there a way we can open this locally without paying for another full license, since we do have one for running the database itself?

Comment: If you can't get below 10 GB, then no. Perhaps you could consider removing some of the data for development ? Or you could have one extra shared database server, for which you pay a license, and have multiple instances of the database on that. If you have multiple developers each needing a copy on their lapptop (and you can't get within Express sizes), MSDN subscriptions for the devs is likely the cheapest option.

Comment: Since it would be a development machine probably the best approach is to use the developer edition. With no other licensing arrangements it is only $75.

Comment: @SeanLange The developer edition has all the features of Enterprise, right? (That's what seems to be the case based on my googling, just thought I'd double check.) If so, the developer edition seems like the way to go, since this system would be for testing purposes. Is there anywhere we can still get the 2008 developer edition? I couldn't find it when I searched, except for one copy on Amazon at a much higher price. Or will the 2014 edition be able to work with our 2008 database without issue?

Comment: You can connect to 2008 with 2014 with no problem at all. And yes, developer edition has all the bells and whistles.

Comment: @SeanLange great, thanks! This sounds like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restore a DB over 4 gigs without a licence.

If we had more information about what you were trying to do with it, we might be able to suggest alternatives.

Is it for analysis? Perhaps you can come up with a SSIS package that copies over only the tables that you need.

Do you need it for backup? Perhaps there is another way to verify things.

Is it for testing? Well, you almost certainly need another licence in this case.

Comment: That limit has been upped to 10 GB with SQL Server **2008 R2** Express (and all the newer versions)